# How to check only some elements of the form?

Tags: javascript

Learning JS. So far have this form (code beneath) ...

So, as you can see from from "formy" element, that it collects all the elements from the form's array.  Is there a simple way to loop through the form, and pick and choose which elements to "error-check"? For example,  I'd like to make sure that only first name, and email are required, and not last name. Is there a way to do that in simple way short of going through each and every single on the form?

Please keep any explanations simple as I'm struggling to learn JS in bite-sizes.

Thank you.

**Clarification**

Not trying to use HTML5 attributes, or JS validation frameworks, but to understand this in pure JS.

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="testyForm" method="post" action="">
            <div id="validation"></div>
            <p><label>First Name<br /><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"></label></p>
            <p><label>Last Name</br /><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"></label></p>
            <p><label>Email<br /><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></label></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </form>
        <script>
            var formy = document.getElementById("testyForm");

            formy.onsubmit = function(event) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
                    if (this.elements[i].value.length == 0) {
                        event.preventDefault(); 
                        this.elements[i].style.border = "1px solid red";
                        this.elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you give them the `required` attribute, then the browser will do it automatically.

Comment: because that's `a)` HTML5 attribute that `b)` requires an updated browser `c)` it's an easy way out, and `d)` trying to actually learn JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array that lists the required elements.

```
        var required_inputs = ['first_name', 'email'];
        formy.onsubmit = function(event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < required_inputs.length; i++) {
                var input = this[required_inputs[i]];
                if (input.value.length == 0) {
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                    input.style.border = "1px solid red";
                    input.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: it's really that simple?

Comment: thank you for showing such a simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add `required` to the form element. This will already trigger browser's implementation of form validation. Of course you can also check in javascript if the form element is required, to style it.

Btw. there are many validation frameworks existing for javascript. Just by reading docs, you'll get an idea of best practices to validate your forms. And they solve problems for you, which you currently not even know that they are existing^^

[Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) is probably the most popular validation framework. I can just recommend to take a look!

Comment: thanks dude. I'm trying to learn JS by getting my hands dirty so to speak. Hence HTML5 attributes and validation frameworks are not what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Well... you asked how to not check all form elements. So you need to select them. Like checking a data-attribute (used by Parsley) or required. You can also use classic class names to mark a field, to get validated.

Comment: awesome. So, how do I do that in js? That's the whole purpose of this query. Not to take the easy way out that I've done in past, but to get down to the nitty-gritty details of JS so I can have confidence in my JS skills.

Comment: This is  how you access data attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

You need to define how to name it, and which attribute (and different value) has which effect for validation. You can also skip the value, like the `required` attribute does. Then you can also just check if the attribute is existing.